# Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an error when y excecute 'rails s' : Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue. the route is : /Documents/proyect  but these file doesn't exist anymore, and i can't start the service for the new project

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you specified the same database as for your old project. Check your `config/database.yml` if that is the case.
If so, you can drop the database manually, or run `rake db:reset` (caution: this deletes your database, make sure you don't have anything you need in there)

Answer (score 0):

```
rake db:reset
```

That's a prefect command!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).